# How to implement custom assets handling in Play2?

Tags: playframework-2.0, authorization, assets

I'm using Play2 Java in my current project and want to implement custom assets hanling.
The main idea is to invoke Assets.at() action from controller action, but I don't know how to handle such things. I can't just call() it. So I want to implement some kind of assets authorization, to distribute assets between user roles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need special considerations for this. Just write a controller that implements your security scheme (using [action composition](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaActionsComposition) for example) and call it as you would call the normal Assets controller.

Comment: Assets.at is a Scala method which uses play.api.mvc.Action as a result, generic Java Action composition uses play.mvc.Action, which suppose to be different things. I don't know how to build Request<AnyContent> to feed up the Scala action apply() method in Java. So I can't mix up Scala and Java actions in general way... that's the trick is all about.